# Can we have XWalkRuntimeLib on google play?

Tags: android, html, runtime

I'm trying make app for android using Crosswalk.

There are two mode for packing: embedded & shared.

In shared mode, apk is smaller.
And it can install both on x86 & arm architecture, because the XWalkRuntimeLibrary installed on device was diffrent.

So, if we publish app shared mode in app store, we will need to publish XWalkRuntimeLib too. 1 library for all app shared mode. (Like Unity3d or Flash Player or Web Browser,...)

I tried upload XWalkRuntimeLib.apk to google play but it said the package already (org.xwalk.runtime.lib)

Can INTEL upload XWalkRuntimeLib.apk to google play?
Shared mode app will easier to publish and update.

Or there is another way to distribute XWAlkRuntimeLib on client?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crosswalk team is working on this.  you can track the progress via this Crosswalk JIRA item:

XWALK-2948: Enable shared mode in xwalk core library
https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-2948